# error - two jssor sliders with two different options in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I'm using two option for two different thumbnails.

It shows an error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of undefined`.

Any help on this issue is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the jssor.slider.debug.js file for a more detailed error message. You can find the raw version on Github here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jssor/slider/master/js/jssor.slider.debug.js

Comment: i have created the two sliders first i have saved the slider into a varable then i  removing the first slider with   $("#slider_inv_container").remove(); and create second slider.